# Difference between multiple variables vs one object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, performance, mobx-react

I am new to programming and reactjs. I tried looking for this but didn't find much to get a good concept about this.

I wonder what is the difference between the two approaches: declaring an object with 3 properties or declaring 3 variables.

**Which one is better performance and resources wise? Will they take up the same amount of memory?**

```
@observable response = {
    foo: null,
    bar: null,
    baz: null
}
```

**vs**

```
@observable foo = null;
@observable bar = null;
@observable baz = null;
```

`const [response, setResponse] = React.useState({foo: null, bar: null, baz: null});`

**vs**

```
const [foo, setFoo] = React.useState(null);
const [bar, setBar] = React.useState(null);
const [baz, setBaz] = React.useState(null);
```

Comment: It also boils down to are you planning to update the state. Are all the 3 pieces going to be updated at once or will they happen at different times. If they are going to be at different times, you have to ensure that you are careful in the update so that no overwrites happen. For example, something like `setResponse({...response, foo: 10})`. If you are using the second way of doing things, you won't have to worry about this.

Comment: for e.g. the scenario is login credentials. username and password. Should they be kept in a single useState or different? Will they take up the same amount of memory?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we should have any much different about performance and resources as well.

The only thing I concern is the way you will use these variables.

For example in case only one variable changes. If you use object, you should do something like below in `setResponse`

```
setResponse({
  ...response
  foo: newFooValue
})
```

If you use three different variables, you just need to do like below, don't worry about the other variables

```
setFoo(newFooValue)
```

That's all about it!

Comment: That I know. What I am trying to ask is will they take up the same amount of memory?

Comment: You can see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

But I don't think we need to consider about memory when using high level language like Javascript.

Comment: I don't think that's the case.